# My time difference formula does not work when it goes to the next day

Tags: php

my time difference formula works but only if the start time is lower than the end time.
when the end time goes to the next day it does not work anymore. see below examples.
Lets say for example my college works from 2pm to 4pm. <-- this works it gives 2 hour difference.
Lets say for example my college works from 11pm to 3am. <-- this does not work it gives 8 hour  difference.

here is my php code:

```
        $to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 22:00:00");
        $from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 03:00:00");
        $hourdiff = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 3600,2). " uur";
        echo "<td>".$hourdiff."</td>";
```

Comment: You're not going to the next day. Both your times are on the same day.

Comment: When I use `$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 03:00:00");` and `$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-12 23:00:00");` I get `4 uur` result.

Comment: Your code prints `10 uur`. That's the difference between 12:00 and 22:00, so what's wrong?

Comment: No it doesn't if you put the correct dates in the variables. See my example above.

Comment: You need to use `2008-12-14` in `$to_time`

Comment: i found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer, just make a if statement.

```
        $from_time = strtotime("2008-12-12 22:00:00");
        $to_time = strtotime("2008-12-12 23:00:00");

        if ($to_time<$from_time){
            $to_time_past = strtotime("2008-12-13 01:00:00");
            $hourdiff = round(abs($to_time_past - $from_time) / 3600,2). " uur";
        }else{
            $hourdiff = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 3600,2). " uur";
        }
```

Comment: I still don't understand why the times are on the same date. How can you start at 11pm and finish at 1am on the same day? `$to_time` should be on the next date.

Comment: But your logic is only needed because the data is wrong. You should fix how you set the variables so that the date is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I see that you're having is that you're not changing the datetime

> Lets say for example my college works from 11pm to 3am. <-- this does not work it gives 8 hour difference.

The most likely explanation I can see is that you're doing something like:

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 11:00:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 03:00:00");
```

This is wrong because 11pm is not 11:00:00 but is 23:00:00. The code should be something like:

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 22:00:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 03:00:00");
```

If it's 3 AM the next day then it should be like:

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 22:00:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-14 03:00:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$date1 = "2014-05-27 01:00:00";
$date2 = "2014-05-28 02:00:00";
$timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);
echo "Difference between two dates is " . $hour = abs($timestamp2 - $timestamp1)/(60*60) . " hour(s)";
```

Comment: What's the difference from his code?

Comment: Explain what you changed and how it solves the problem. I don't see a difference that matters.

Comment: `60*60` is the same as `3600`. You're not rounding to 2 decimal places, but that's negligible.

Comment: Last line was different when I read the question.

Comment: i found the answer